# How to return first item from a nested JSON array using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm currently experiencing a few problems whilst parsing .JSON.

Ok, so 'element.lineStatuses' can return 1 or 2 opjects in an array but I only want to return the first object from array.  I've tried a multitude of different solutions, however, none seem to work...

Please note: I am unable to use '$.first()' as a solution as my application depends on an older version of jQuery.

```
   $.ajax({
                    url:"https://api.tfl.gov.uk/line/mode/tube,overground,dlr,tflrail/status",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    type: 'get',
                    cache: false,
                     beforeSend: function() {
        $("#loadingDiv").show();
    },
                    success: function(data){


                        console.log(data);
        var jObject = data;


$.each(jObject, function(index, element) {

       $("#lines").append("<li class=\"lineName\"><h2>" + element.name + "</h2></li>");

      // console.log(element.name);



      // element.lineStatuses; can contain 1 or 2 opjects in an array but i only want to return the first objectin array.

       var status = element.lineStatuses;


        // loop to get line status
        // gets all objects

        $.each(status, function(index, element) { 

            var desc = element.statusSeverityDescription;
            //console.log(desc);

            $("#lines").append("<p class=\"currentStatus\">" + desc + "</p>");

        });

});




            }// end success

    });// end ajax
```

Comment: `element.lineStatuses[0]` would be the first element..... if that is all you are after that is what you would use

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not work for me.. :(

Comment: Well how did you use it? You can't just replace that single line and expect the rest of the script to work. Especially the `$.each()` part after it as `status` would no longer be an array and would therefore be looping over the element's properties instead of looping over elements.

Comment: It can be done by replacing that single line! thanks for your input

Comment: I meant it wouldnt work by replacing with the line i mentioned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you what you want is to get only the first element of an array-like object in an array of its own, you can use [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to create a shallow copy:

```
var status = [].slice.call(element.lineStatuses, 0, 1);
```

If you're sure `element.lineStatuses` is an array and not simply *array-like* you can use the simpler:

```
var status = element.lineStatuses.slice(0, 1);
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked... I've never encountered 'slice' before.. I will look at the documentation.

Comment: You're welcome @AaronStrickland. I'm glad I could help you 

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var status = element.lineStatuses[0];
```